# SSRS Multiple data set with dynamic (PIVOT) columns need to do calculation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have 2 data sets from SQL SERVER. Each data set will contain related data. I am doing a pivot operation/using the matrix in SSRS builder to display the flat data. Now I need to do the calculation of these result sets to display in the report. How will I do it in SSRS?

I have attached the sample data here.

[image: 1]

Comment: You can do this using LOOKUP() or LOOKUPSET() but it would be easier if you could join the data in your SQL query. Is there any reason why you cannot do the join in SQL?

Comment: I have more calculations with the same and different data sets to do in the below section of the report. whats I have mentioned is only 1/4 of the requirement. So for each calculation, if I use different queries then the data load may be huge. I will try out with Lookupset function. I have tried one customer code and it did work fine.